# Firebase Realtime Database setValue do nothing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have strengh behavior of Firebase Realtime Database:

When I write data to the reference, nothing happens. I do it like:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("devices/" + token + "/" + actionId);
myRef.setValue(value);
```

I set a value change listener before, and it triggers! onChange, like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("devices/" + token + "/" + actionId);
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      // this is triggered after I setValue with all the changes
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
myRef.setValue(value);
```

but when I check on the web using Firebase dashboard, there are no changes, value is "null". As like phone just simulates these changes. This happens only on ONE of my devices. It works with the same code on all other devices. And it has been working before on this device. Any ideas?

The device is:  Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935F) Android Version: 7.0 
Used libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
```

Comment: What value do the `token` and `actionId` variables have?

Comment: @AlexMamo token is a FCM token and actionId is an integer.

Comment: And contain values, are no null, right?

Comment: They are both not null. Like I said this happens only on one device. I could not find what the problem is. But hard-reset helped. This is of course not the right solution, therefore I will not write it as answer to this topic. Maybe someone will face the same problem and this topic can help somehow.

Comment: did you figure out the solution to your problem in the end?

Comment: @KamilJanowski, no sadly not. After hard-reset I didn't faced this problem again.

Comment: I have the same issue :D previous project had no problem. My problem occurs on every device. I see on change data but it does not reflect on firebase db